# Sitecore Experience Editor Ribbon not loading- InvalidOperationException: SpriteStorageNode

Tags: experience-editor

I have a sitecore 9 project. When i load the Experience Editor the Ribbon iframe has a Server Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: SpriteStorageNode
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a fresh Sitecore 9 install or an upgraded instance?

Comment: @GeorgeChang it's a fresh Sitecore 9 install. It actually worked on my local server but started getting issues once i moved it to an azure server.

Comment: Havw you checked the DLLs loaded in your app to make sure they are all the right versions?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this issue?

Comment: @RichardForrest no, i ended up doing a fresh SC9 install. This issue was during an "upgrade".